# Flutter Dart: Set text on background image according to screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I want to set text just as provided in design picture but I am getting text on top of my background image and I can't set it accordingly..
I have tried other things like putting "Container" on top and then applying Scaffold underneath but also it didn't work...
or is there any text property like "Margin" to margin text accordingly and other components too..
Here's my code:

````
return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                height: size.height * 1,
                width: size.width * 1,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('images/bg.png'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      
                      ('Kleine.'),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    
                    ),
Text(
//code 
),
                  ],
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```[![This is what I want][1]][1]
[![This is what I am getting "keline" on top][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kpK5.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4aIX.png
I want my text and other widgets to justify accordingly just as given in the provided image.
````

Comment: can you send a picture of your result? ... I am not getting your question

Comment: @Why_So_Ezz Please check

Answer (score 0):

Use `Stack` Widget for this purpose and `positioned` or `Align` widget for set Text or image as per your requirement

sample code

```
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Stack(
            children:<Widget> [
              Center(
                child: new Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/Login BG.png',
                  width: size.width,
                  height: size.height,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: size.height/4.5,
                left: size.width/7,
                right: size.width/7,
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/Logo.png",
                  height: 200,
                  width: 200,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: size.height/2.2,
                left: size.width/11,
                right: size.width/11,
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: 320,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _textLoginUserMnameController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: size.height/1.8,
                left: size.width/11,
                right: size.width/11,
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: 320,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _textLoginUserpasswordController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: size.height/1.4,
                left: size.width/5,
                right: size.width/5,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 45,
                    width: 160,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("Sign in"),
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      gradient: new LinearGradient(
                        colors: [
                       Color.fromARGB(255, 45, 120, 234),
                       Color.fromARGB(255, 89, 149, 240)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {

            //Login
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Stack widget in the scaffold body and in the children add the image first and thn add the column for all the text and textfields with appropriate padding and sizedboxes .